# Including rows with no values in SQL query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Running the following query in my `SQL SERVER 2016` database:

```
SELECT
    u.idnumber,
    gi.idnumber AS code,
    gg.finalgrade AS grade
FROM
    grades AS gg 
INNER JOIN grade_items AS gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON gg.userid = u.id
WHERE gi.idnumber IN ('436','434','313','002','135')
AND (u.idnumber = 'JohnBrown-xyz123);
```

gives me this result:

```
-------------------------
idnumber    code    grade
-------------------------
John12558   313     96
John12558   135     83
```

How can I include a row for ALL the 5 gi.idnumber's, including the rows with no grade?

```
-------------------------
idnumber    code    grade
-------------------------
John12558   436
John12558   434
John12558   313     96
John12558   002
John12558   135     83
```

Database tables:

### user

id PK

### grade_items

id PK

### grade_grades

grade_grades.itemid FK (grade_items)

grade_grades.userid FK (user)

Comment: Use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `cross join` to see all you want:

```
select 
    u.idnumber,
    gi.idnumber code,
    ISNULL(gg.finalgrade, 0) grade
from  users u
    cross join grade_items gi
    left outer join grades gg on gg.itemid = gi.id  and gg.userid = u.id
where gi.idnumber in ('436','434','313','002','135')
    and u.idnumber = 'JohnBrown-xyz123'
```

nulls in `finalgrade` cannot be replaced with 'N/A' because they are numbers, not strings, I replaced them with zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value` construct like that :

```
select tt.idnumber, 
       t.idnumber AS code, 
       tt.grade 
from (values ('436'), ('434'), ('313'), ('002'), ('135')) t (idnumber) 
left join (select
                 u.idnumber,
                 gi.idnumber AS code,
                 gg.finalgrade AS grade
           from grades AS gg 
           inner join grade_items AS gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id 
           inner join users AS u ON gg.userid = u.id
           where u.idnumber = 'JohnBrown-xyz123') tt on left(tt.code, 3) = t.idnumber
```

If, *idnumber* has numeric type, then you don't need to use `' '`.

Comment: Will the solution change if I change my `WHERE` clause to:


`WHERE LEFT(gi.idnumber, 3) IN ('436','434','313','002','135')`


for when gi.idnumber is a longer string, like:


`WHERE LEFT(gi.idnumber, 3) IN ('436-test-123','434-abc-xyz','313-tst-123','002-xxx-558','135-zzz-888')`

Comment: @luisdev.. Do it at `ON` clause since `JOINS`  used instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: Sorry Yogesh, what do you mean by "Do it at ON clause"?

Comment: This finally worked for me:

`SELECT 
tt.idnumber, 
tt.id, 
t.idnumber AS examcode, 
tt.itemname, 
tt.grade
FROM (values ('436'), ('434'), ('313'), ('002'), ('135'), ('148'), ('104')) t (idnumber) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
u.id,
u.idnumber,
gi.itemname,
gi.idnumber AS code,
gg.finalgrade AS grade
FROM mdl_grade_grades AS gg 
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_user AS u ON gg.userid = u.id
WHERE u.id = '75449'
) tt ON LEFT(tt.code,3) = t.idnumber
WHERE tt.itemname IS NOT NULL
AND tt.grade IS NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "no value" is `NULL` then just add an extra clause to your `WHERE`:

```
WHERE (LEFT(gi.idnumber, 3) IN ('436','434','313','002','135')
   OR gi.idnumber IS NULL)
```

Edit: Apaprently, the above does not work, which implies that "no value" does not mean `NULL`. you could, instead, therefore try:

```
    WHERE (LEFT(gi.idnumber, 3) IN ('436','434','313','002','135','')
```

If this doesn't work, please provide **consumable** sample data, which we can test against: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: Yes, "no value" is NULL.

Comment: That still gives me the original 2 rows instead of the desired 5 rows (unless I didn't do it right?).

Comment: @luisdev Sounds like the column `gi.idnumber` doesn't have the value `NULL` then.

Comment: @luisdev  I've added an alternative for you.

Comment: gi.idnumber is never null. gg.finalgrade can be null. If it is, then I want to include a row with a "N/A" for that gg.finalgrade.

Comment: OK, this changes things quite a bit. HOw can you link `grade_items` to `users`? Sounds like you need a `LEFT JOIN`, but I don't have DDL so i'd have to guess it.

Comment: You can't link grade_items to users directly. grade_items doesn't contain any USER data. grade_grades has the foreign keys for both the  user table and the grade_items table. I added part of the DDL to my main post.

Comment: DDL is on https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Grades#Database_structures, but that's a huge document store.

Comment: Edit your post just the the relevant DDL; you can't expect people to read that and make the DDL and sample data up.